# How to wire a new ceiling light fixture in the UK?

Tags: light

I'm installing a ceiling light. It has, as pictured, an L and N.

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

My old light is as pictured here:

[image]

Can someone help me with where the wires should go? Would the red wires get put into a Wago?

I'm in the UK.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Edit your general location into your question.  Not sure, but I think blue wire equals neutral(N) and brown is power(L).  Red wires seem to be just connected together, but no function there.

Comment: We need like, country.  Because electrical systems differ.

Comment: You're asking about red wires, yet there is no picture anywhere of where these red wires are. How about adding in those pics.

Comment: @FreeMan I can see 2 red wires.  Rather grubby red wires, but definitely not black.

Answer (score 1):

The blue wire would be a neutral and the brown the hot, this is more of a standard in the UK than the US but I have installed equipment in the US with the same color coding for the wiring.

Comment: So just connect the red wires to a wago s they aren't serving a purpose. Brown to live and blue to neutral which I knew ready just didn't know what to do with the red which appeared to be doing nothing

Comment: Some light sensors use the red as an output without knowing what the red are for cap them

Comment: @LouiseWright I'm sure the red wires are serving a purpose.

Comment: @LouiseWright Its a bit hard to tell from the pictures but there looks to be 2 red wires twisted together into the connector? If this is so then they're just continuing the ring - Simon B is correct "The black that was connected to brown should really have a bit of brown (or red) sleeving shoved over it to say it's the switched live".
Separating these 2 red wires might cause other lights to stop working (depending on the rest of the wiring) so don't touch these.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the old light was wired correctly.  That may be a big assumption, depending on who wired it.

On the old light, brown is live, blue is neutral.  So the black that was connected to the brown goes to the new L.  The black that was connected to the blue goes to the new N.  The red wires should still be joined together.

The black that was connected to brown should really have a bit of brown (or red) sleeving shoved over it to say it's the switched live.  Because that would distinguish it from the other black.

I see no Earth there.  Some old installations (up to the mid 1960's) didn't have an Earth on the lighting circuit.  If that's the case here, don't use any light fitting that requires an Earth.